# Pdf not previewing in browser but always downloading - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pdf, download

I've come to seek help as I can not figure out what is going on with the pdf files on the site I am working on.

Normally, if you have a direct link to a pdf, Chrome, and most other browsers preview the file from within the browser. E.g. when I paste this link into Chrome:

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

It opens the pdf in the browser.

However, any pdf files on my site are automatically downloaded when the direct link is accessed. I've noticed that it does work on safari on the iPad but it doesn't work in Chrome on the pc.

I've found many people who wished the opposite but I found only few who gave an answer to my question. I tried editing the .htaccess file like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
    ForceType application/pdf
    Header set Content-Disposition inline
</FilesMatch>
```

This did not work.

I quickly tested it with a clean wordpress install on another host and there it works just fine. Any ideas?

Here's the link to the file:

http://cgdespreng.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Test-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding it within a Google Docs Viewer:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://cgdespreng.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Test-pdf.pdf

Comment: please add detailed answer

Comment: These look like automated responses because anyone actually reading the entry will see that it provides a 'detailed answer': "embed within a GD viewer" followed by an example using the problematic test document of the original post.

This is not a 'look at the the information linked by this URL for a solution'!